# Flutter - Physical device is connected with USB debugging on but still shows "no devices connected"

Tags: flutter

**Question**: I have my physical device connected, developer option enabled, USB debugging enabled as well, android SDK installed also but still when I do `flutter run` it says "no devices connected or found".

**What I tried before**: I have been researching and finding since morning on this but still issue is not resolved.

I tried running `flutter devices --verbose` as well and got below output.

````dart
[ +130 ms] executing: [C:\Src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +114 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\Src\flutter/] git tag --points-at b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[  +71 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[   +1 ms] 2.0.4
[  +85 ms] executing: [C:\Src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +62 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\Src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +46 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +126 ms] executing: [C:\Src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +50 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +214 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +136 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +56 ms] executing: C:\Users\Mit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +87 ms] List of devices attached
[   +9 ms] No devices detected.

           Run "flutter emulators" to list and start any available device emulators.

           If you expected your device to be detected, please run "flutter doctor" to diagnose potential
           issues. You
           may also try increasing the time to wait for connected devices with the --device-timeout flag.
           Visit
           https://flutter.dev/setup/ for troubleshooting tips.
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\Mit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +67 ms] List of devices attached
[  +21 ms] "flutter devices" took 464ms.
[ +244 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 232ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 0```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you
````

Comment: can you please provide result of `flutter devices`?

Comment: @Nuts yes sure!                                                                                                                                             
    flutter devices
No devices detected.

Run "flutter emulators" to list and start any available device emulators.

If you expected your device to be detected, please run "flutter doctor" to diagnose potential issues. You
may also try increasing the time to wait for connected devices with the --device-timeout flag. Visit
https://flutter.dev/setup/ for troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several causes, for example the connection to the device might not be authorized.
Try running `adb devices` in the terminal, the output will show whether it is detected and connected properly.

Comment: Hey, It says adb is not recognized as an internal or external command when I execute this command in terminal.